# How secure is Splikity

Tags: password-management

There's a password app called Splikity. It features:

- Military-Grade Encryption
- Encrypted on Your Device
- Strongest Security in the Industry
- Continual Security Tests

Although I'm sold on the fact that it uses AES256 and SHA256, I know that security is not only dependent on the tools one uses, but also on how he/she uses them.

So my question is: **Is Splikity actually secure?** Is there a way to know how secure an app like that is?

Comment: I  know nothing about the product but from my experience such  exaggerated  claims like military grade or strongest security are more often found in insecure software than in well designed secure software.

Comment: Military-grade means nothing. If they claim "strongest in industry" do they publish who tested? How they scored? Has it been peer reviewed? Basically, as Steffen said, treat all those claims as marketing spiel, and instead, find one that has extensive peer review and positive scores. It is likely to be better.

Comment: @RoryAlsop Many legitimate companies offer 'Military-grade encryption'. It is called being [FIPS 140-2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FIPS_140-2) compliant. I make no claims about this company however.

Comment: Generally, military grade statements are not made by companies who are FIPS 140. Those that have FIPS compliance tend to state that :-)

Comment: Perhaps you could try to be more specific: "Secure" against which threats (e.g. breaking encryption, guessing passwords, rootkits, backdoors, etc)? How are you using it (e.g. on one machine, vs sharing the pwd file publicly vs cloud app)? What are you using (e.g. just protecting passwords, password generation, automatic form filling, etc)?

Comment: Additionally, I doubt you'll get a good answer for this, as it stands (even with the missing context) - I doubt anyone here has done a proper in-depth review of that specific product, and even if they did likely not able to share it (NDA), and even if the could it would only apply to a specific version, and what happens after that? On the other hand, I think a MUCH better question would be what you *started* to ask - how can I know if a password management app is secure enough (for a specific use-case)? How do I compare apps, what should I look for, what features / attributes are important?

Comment: @RoryAlsop Agreed. If a company makes a military-grade encryption claim and the FIPS compliance statement can't easily be found, something is amiss.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way to be completely certain it's secure.  There's no way we know of to be completely certain *anything* is secure.

Failing complete security, there are several ways to be *reasonably* assured that the security level is adequate.

The best way it to have the product audited by people who are knowledgeable about such things...Both the cryptography side, and the secure software development side.   Additionally, not only does the current implementation need to appear to be reasonably free of flaws, but they need to have plans for maintenance and patching to ensure it stays that way, and that if issues *are* found in the future, they can be swiftly remediated.

If you can get a through audit done, it's also reasonable to expect that something built by respected members of the applied crypto and secure software communities is probably alright to use.   I don't know if this is or not.

So, if you don't have insight into the software itself, or at least the creators of the software, then no, there is no good way to adequately determine if it is well designed and implemented or not.

That said, the "military-grade" marketing bullet aside, there are no glaring flaws in the approach they describe.   AES-256 is a fine choice.   PBKDF2 is not as good as scrypt or bcrypt for this purpose, but perhaps more likely to be already correctly implemented on the platforms they're using, and it's good enough.  They make it clear that decryption is only done client side, and there is no master key recovery process, which is good.  They claim all communication between server and client is done via SSL (hopefully really TLS) which, if done properly, is correct.

There are things we can't know from the description alone.   Are they using AES correctly?   Is the number of PDKDF2 rounds really adequate for the purpose?  Are they managing the decrypted data, password and key materially securely on the client?   These are a few of the questions that I would want answered before choosing a product like this...Though really, I would be hard-pressed to pick an also-ran in this market space over something like KeePass or Password1 in any case, without a specifically compelling reason.   There's just less chance that it'll get the appropriate scrutiny and that any issues it *does* have will be brought to the surface for resolution.